# How to make BundleTransformer work on Windows Server Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, bundletransformer

Ever since we found dotLess stopped working for us our ASP.NET MVC project has been using BundleTransformer for our LESS bundling and minification. We are trying to migrate our CI build agents to use Windows Server Core (headless) and away from Windows Server Standard. When we did this we started receiving Internal Server Errors when trying to hit our pages. This seems to be blowing up inside of BundleTransformer.

We initially were using BundleTransformer with http://www.nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie

From reading this post I thought maybe it was that we were missing the dependency on Internet Explorer.
http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/discussions/454495

I tried to use the v8 engine switcher and started getting server errors on my Windows Standard setup.
http://www.nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8

Has anyone successfully managed to get BundleTransformer working on a Windows Server Core environment? Anything would help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) before you install the JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8 package?

Give an example of the error message.

Comment: This was the solution we used to fix the problem. I forgot to mark this solved. Thank you for offering help.