# Faulting module name: ChakraCore.DLL

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012, chakracore

I have some problem with BundleTransformer.Less

Everyting is fine on my local Windows 10. But my Ms Server 2014 not working with both `JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie` and  `JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore`.

I am getting below error with ChakraCore

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108835
Faulting module name: ChakraCore.DLL, version: 1.10.1.0, time stamp: 0x5b45ff01
```

Is there any easest way for rendering less with c#?

Comment: Have you installed the Visual C++ runtime on the Windows Server?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274402

Comment: Yess both 2015 and 2017 are installed.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/5595

Comment: I have tried with lotfs of versions. But there was no changes.

Comment: Now it is working when I enabe 32 bit application. And don't understand why?